# How to add a page to header that is outside of WordPress?

Tags: menus, pages

I have a page on my site that is not a page in WordPress. How can I add it to the header?

EDIT: The page is .php. It is outside of the theme structure.

Comment: need some more information.  is the page .html? .php? Is it in your theme file structure, or somewhere else?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: I'm assuming it must stay outside the theme structure?  on the same server though?

Comment: I guess it doesn't need to stay outside the theme structure...

Comment: ok took a stab.  assuming the file can be moved within the theme structure.

Answer (score 1):

The code you want is:

```
<?php include 'yourfile.php' ?>
```

Place the file in the same directory as header.php.

EDIT: depending on the nature of the content, and how often you will reuse, you may also choose to use this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a template header comment and add your site as [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates).

Just add the following line on top of your file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My lovely standalone page
 */
```

Then add another *page* and choose your new template from the dropdown/select on the meta box on the right. You don't have to add any content or anything (I'd add a title in case it gets used) and your site will be integrated straight into WordPress. You then can even add it to menus, etc.